# Youtube HTML5 videos playing very slow with distorted sound - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, youtube, html5

I have to restart the computer to fix it but the problem keeps returning. I have used firefox and Gnome browser and the problem persists on both. What could be causing this?

PC specs:

- Intel core i5 5250u
- Intel HD 6000 graphics
- 16Gb RAM

Comment: goto **http://www.youtube.com/html5** and check if something error if their's no error click firefox on supported browser section it will lead you to page click refresh browser

Comment: if you find any error run this command **`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras `**

Comment: @MohamedSlama I tried both solutions but the problem is still there.

Comment: Same issue for me.  I already think of buying more powerful computer